# help to find homes for strays vs. help strays find homes

Tags: meaning, difference

Do the following sentences mean the same? Any nuance?

> a. The volunteer helps stray animals find homes.

> b. The volunteer helps to find homes for stray animals.

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking, you wouldn't say (a), although you could probably get away with it. A volunteer doesn't assist stray animals in their pursuit of a home. A volunteer finds a home for a stray animal.

You need to remove "to" in (b). It should be:

> The volunteer helps find homes for stray animals.

If it were a real estate agent instead of a volunteer, and they were people instead of animals, then there probably wouldn't be any difference between the two:

> A real estate agent helps clients find homes.
>
> A real estate agent helps find homes for clients.

The second usage might suggest that the real estate agent is playing a more active role in the searching, but it's very subtle.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a difference. (a) shows how the volunteers helps the stray animals *to find homes*, but the volunteer does not actually find the home himself/herself, but actually *helps* the stray animal do so. (b) shows how the volunteers helps *find the homes himself/herself* for stray animals.

Comment: That's the literal meaning of (a), but we know that stray animals don't actually arrange to re-home themselves!